# Why isn't this XSLT-stylesheet working the way i want on this XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm a beginner in XML/XSLT and i'm having troubles making an XSLT-stylesheet transform an XML to another XML.

Here's my XML-file:

```
<Book
  xmlns:qws="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <Price>168</Price>
  <Author>
    <Fnamn>Richard</Fnamn>
    <Mnamn>Eric</Mnamn>
    <Snamn>Meyer</Snamn>
  </Author>
  <Title>Multimedia Learning</Title>
</Book>
```

I want to transform that XML to the following

```
<Firstname>Richard></Firstname>
<MiddleName>Eric></Middlename>
<Lastname>Meyer</Lastname>
```

Here's my failed attempt with my XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="hej"
                xmlns:qws="http://www.w3schools.com"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/qws:Book">
    <h>Information</h>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="qws:Author"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="qws:Author">
    <Firstname><xsl:value-of select="qws:Fnamn"/></Firstname>
    <MiddleName><xsl:value-of select="qws:Mnamn"/></MiddleName>
    <Lastname><xsl:value-of select ="qws:Snamn"/></Lastname>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is not correct. There are many ways to do it. This is an example xslt to transform your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Information</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">First Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Middle Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Last Name</th>            
          </tr>       
          <xsl:for-each select="Book/Author">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Fnamn"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Mnamn"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Snamn"/>
              </td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                Price : <xsl:value-of select="../../Book/Price"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]

**Updated to produce reformatted xml as requested.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Book>
          <xsl:for-each select="Book/Author">
            <Author>
              <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="Fnamn"/>
              </FirstName>
              <MiddleName>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Mnamn"/>
              </MiddleName>
              <LastName>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Snamn"/>
              </LastName>
            </Author>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </Book>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by xpath? And why is "Price" included in the stylesheet?

Comment: xpath is the query language that you use in xslt. For an example when I use `Book/Author`, it gets pointed to `<Author>` element. When the pointer is at `Author` element, you can call `<xsl:value-of select="Fnamn"/>` query to get `<Fnamn>` element value, so on and so forth. When the pointer is at `<Fname>` level, if you need to retrieve the value of `<Price>` element, you have to make the pointer jump two levels up. That's why I have used `../../` in front  of `Book/Price`.

Comment: Downvoting this answer, because although it provides a working solution to the problem (a) it doesn't explain why the OP's attempt is failing, and (b) it's not particularly good form to use for-each here rather than apply-templates, especially when teaching beginners.

Comment: This worked and i do undestand the logic better now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things: your attempted script does not produce a root element, rendering it a not well-formed xml. Plus, you do not need to use the prefix because the targeted nodes are not in the namespace bound to the prefix . Now, if you want to re-use original Book, consider using `local-name()` or `name()` as a defined `<xsl:element>` name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:qws="http://www.w3schools.com"
                exclude-result-prefixes="qws msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Book">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <h>Information</h>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Author"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Author">
    <Firstname><xsl:value-of select="Fnamn"/></Firstname>
    <MiddleName><xsl:value-of select="Mnamn"/></MiddleName>
    <Lastname><xsl:value-of select ="Snamn"/></Lastname>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Book>
  <h>Information</h>
  <Firstname>Richard</Firstname>
  <MiddleName>Eric</MiddleName>
  <Lastname>Meyer</Lastname>
</Book>
```

Comment: "*you do not need to prefix the referenced nodes with qws since it is already a declared namespace in xml*". That is not the correct reason. The real reason is that the targeted nodes are not in the namespace bound to the prefix.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted text accordingly. I wish you experts could answer XSLT questions on Python/PHP/R/Java/VBA threads. Many programmers are running nested loops to transform/re-write XML files and hardly know of this good, useful language!

Comment: This did indeed work. Thanks to all here that have answered. I now understand the logic of XSLT better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your attempt fails is this:

Although your input XML contains a namespace declaration `xmlns:qws="http://www.w3schools.com"`, this declaration is not used anywhere and is entirely redundant. None of the elements in the input XML are in a namespace, and your attempt to address them using a prefix bound to the `"http://www.w3schools.com'` namespace fails because of that.

All you need to do is remove the `qws:` prefix from your `match` and `select` expressions, and it will work.

Well, almost all: you should also remove the unneeded namespace declarations: 
`xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` and `xmlns:qws="http://www.w3schools.com"`, as well as the `exclude-result-prefixes="hej"` part (you haven't even declared a namespace using the `hej` prefix).

Comment: Something really is strange is going on. I tried adjusting my XSL according to your suggestion but the output is the whole document instead of the specified template(Author).

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed that. It was a stupid problem that i was too stupid to see immediately. But the problem now is that the only output i get on Internet Explorer is the "Information" header and not the value of Fname, Mname and Sname. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @Rengaw I am not sure I understand what you describe. Keep in mind, though, that a browser is designed to display HTML, not to test XSL transformations. If your purpose is to display the information from your XML in a browser, you need to redefine the task - starting with the expected result.